# TextView not starting at left

Tags: android

Here's a picture to help me explain my problem:

The black box is the whole screen. The red box is the `TextView`. The green is the text. When I run my code, it looks like the left screen, but I want to it look as it does on the right. (start from left)

[image]

Here is the `TextView` code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_ruta"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/info_sumary"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/day_seven_id" />
```

When trying to add `android:gravity="left"` or `="start"` it does not help with my problem. What am I missing here?

Comment: use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and make sure container should have match_parent too and if still problem stays post the entire layout

Comment: What's the parent layout? Try posting your full layout.

Comment: @PavneetSingh that took care of my problem! Thank you! "answer" if you would like me to accept and upvote.

Comment: @ReazMurshed changing to android:layout_width="match_parent" fixed it

Comment: @Carlton I think you got it wrong match_parent was always there in your image wasn't it? check the red line .. what is it ? and to make a view align left why the hell you make it match_parent ? doesn't make sence

Comment: @CharukaSilva How do you mean? the red line is the textview, how it looks on my screen. But the green, which is the actual text (just painted the whole area green) and it did not start at the far left of my textview, it got "centered" a little bit.

Comment: @Carlton  tell me why you try gravity left or right then ill explain what happened

Comment: @CharukaSilva I was not sure what was causing to center like that, and I thought maybe it would help stretch the text to the far left with gravity. (Sorry Im new to Android)

Comment: @Carlton okay .I ll tell you why i disagreed.you have that red line you mentioned it as the boundaries of  your textView if  its the case then its already match_parent .. what i'm saying is you can't make textView boundaries match parent and also assign your text inside it as match_parent , because once your t.view is match_parent its content goes match_parent too.In that case only reason to have white space in left and right is android:layout_marginStart and android:layout_marginEnd according to your view. did you get that?

Comment: @CharukaSilva Yea I think so, except the last part. Could you explain please?

Comment: what i told was according to the image on the left side you dont have a TextView to match_parent in width its already there. If that was the real case that space in right and left is due to your margins that you specified .People who gave the answer gave it looking at your xml code I did it considering  your left image

Comment: @CharukaSilva oh sorry I get it now. Thanks for your comments and answers! :)

Comment: so if i posted an answer i will ask you to remove the margins . just mentioned to clear your idea :) good luck

Comment: @CharukaSilva Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use android:layout_width="match_parent"` instead of fixed width `android:layout_height="80dp"` so it would be

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_ruta"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"                             

    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/info_sumary"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/day_seven_id" />
```

`match_parent` with `android:width` mean cover the complete width which is occupied by the parent container.

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:gravity="left"` on attributes of XML.

The `match_parent` is fundamental for this.

Comment: Thank you! It  Works! Will upvote but cant "accept" sorry @pavneetSingh commented first. But thanks again.